# How do you do a self join in a KDB query?

Tags: self-join, kdb

Is it possible in KDB to do the following:

(giving you equivalent in SQL)

```
select column1 
  from table1 alias1
    join table1 alias2
  where alias1.column2 = alias2.column2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
q)t:([]k: 1 2 1; v:`A`B`C)
q)ej[`k;t;t]
k v
---
1 A
1 C
2 B
1 A
1 C
```

**UPDATE**: you can filter results however you like:

```
q)select from ej[`k;t;t] where (v=`A) or k=2
k v
---
1 A
2 B
1 A
```

**UPDATE 2:** If you all you need is find duplicates you don't need to self-join your table at all:

```
q)t:([]k: 1 2 3 4 5; v:`A`B`A`C`C)
q)select from t where 1<(count;v)fby v
k v
---
1 A
3 A
4 C
5 C
```

Comment: Thank you. Half way there:). How about a where clause? Say I got t:([]k: 1 2 3; v:\`A\`B\`A) and I want the query to return to me "1 A" and "3 A" (on same or different lines) which have the same `v.

Comment: Looks like I don't understand what you want to return. What is `3 A`? There is no 3 in my example.

Comment: In my example there is. In your update the where clauses contain direct values, I wanted to avoid that (like in the SQL example). So far Michael's answer below is best for my needs, but yours is better overall match for the original question.

Comment: @tonank: Looking at @Michael's answer it occurred to me that you are looking for a way to select duplicates i.e. those rows that have `v` values equal. I updated my answer again to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd question (wont let me comment, so adding here), you could maybe do something like the below

```
t:([]k: 1 2 3 4 5; v:`A`B`A`C`C) 

select from t where v in (exec v from (select count i by v from t) where x>1)

ungroup select from (`v xgroup t) where (count each k)>1
```

Comment: Thank you. This really answers my needs, I marked the other answer though, as it more directly relates to the question..